# ODBC connects but authentication fails on users table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access, odbc

We have sql 2008 running in mixed mode. The site where sql is running the ODBC connection works and ms access authenticates against the user table. We have an IPSec vpn to a satellite office using Cisco routers on a 100mb leased line. ODBC connector connects when setting up the connector (& my udl) but ms access authentication fails. Nothing has changed on the server or ms access and it been running fine for the past 6 years.

I have disabled the firewall on win 2016 server
Tested the connection using a udl file

Comment: Please, add the error log if there's any.